# ReactJS onClick get DIV IDs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, onclick, getelementbyid

I have 3 divs and onClick, I want to grab the ID of each div.

(Eventually, I want to add a shuffle function, to shuffle the divs).  But for the time being, I just want to get the ID of each.

If I console.log `this` on each div `onClick`, I only seem to get the values of the last div. No matter which div I click.

What's the best way to do this?

I've read about `React.createRef()`, but this does not seem to generate a unique ID per div.  (I've read it's best not to use `document.getElementByID()` in react).

So what's the best way to do this?

Here's my code so far!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

class Cylinders extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      ball: ''
    }
  }


  componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log('mount');
  }

  generateShuffle = () => {
    console.log('shuffel');
    console.log('this', this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <section>

          <div className="columns is-mobile">
            <div className="column">
              <h1 className="title has-text-black is-size-2">Cylinders Game</h1>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="columns is-mobile">
            <div className="column">
              <button className="title has-text-black is-size-2">Ball container</button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="columns is-mobile">
            <div className="column">
              <div className="columns is-multiline">
                <div
                  onClick={this.generateShuffle}
                  className="hat1"
                  // ref="1"
                  ref={this.myRef}
                  id="1">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="column">
              <div className="columns is-multiline">
                <div 
                  className="hat2" 
                  ref={this.myRef} 
                  id="2" 
                  onClick={this.generateShuffle}>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="column">
              <div className="columns is-multiline">
                <div className="hat3" 
                  ref={this.myRef} 
                  id="3" 
                  onClick={this.generateShuffle}>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Cylinders;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try a different approach and draw the elements from an array you can shuffle more easily, like that:

```
  const [things, setThings] = useState([
    { name: "Thing" },
    { name: "Other Thing" },
    { name: "Another Thing" }
  ]);


  const shuffle = () => {
    // shuffle things variables
    const shuffled = things.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    setThings([...shuffled]);
  };
```

And render them :

```
   <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={shuffle}>Shuffle list</button>
      </div>
      {things.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div
            className="something"
            onClick={() => handleClick(item)}
            key={item.name + index}
          >
            {item.name}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

It's written in functional component way, but you can see an example [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-chaplygin-puvf1)

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful and definitely the direction I wanted to go in. Your shuffle approach is much cleaner, than what I was thinking, which is great. And I managed to get the div values from this method too. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

use shortid

```
npm i shortid
```

source:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

var shortid = require('shortid');

class Cylinders extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      ball: ''
    }
  }


  componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log('mount');
  }

  generateShuffle = (e) => {
    console.log('shuffel');
    console.log('this', e.target.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <section>

<div className="columns is-mobile">
  <div className="column">
    <h1 className="title has-text-black is-size-2">Cylinders Game</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div className="columns is-mobile">
  <div className="column">
    <button className="title has-text-black is-size-2">Ball container</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div className="columns is-mobile">
  <div className="column">
    <div className="columns is-multiline">
      <div
        onClick={generateShuffle}
        className="hat1"
        // ref="1"        
        id={shortid.generate()}>div1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="column">
    <div className="columns is-multiline">
      <div 
        className="hat2" 

        id={shortid.generate()}
        onClick={generateShuffle}>
          div2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="column">
    <div className="columns is-multiline">
      <div className="hat3" 

        id={shortid.generate()}
        onClick={generateShuffle}>
          div3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</section>      
    );
  }
}

export default Cylinders;
```